# Parsing datetime in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Why this throws an exception and how to fix this one?

[image]

Comment: How difficult would it have been to past the **actual code** instead of a screen shot? This makes it more difficult to answer you question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The year in the string is `12` and your format string is expecting a 4 digit year `yyyy`.

These don't match, hence the failure.

Either use the correct format string `dd-MM-yy`, or if you expect both options, use an overload that takes an array of strings as format strings.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the pattern `dd-MM-yyyy` but give only `dd-MM-yy` with using `30-04-12`